# maven t7mp tomcat plugin manager application

Tags: tomcat, maven

How to get the manager application working in t7mp plugin. I copied the manager application to the webapps folder of the tomcat downloaded by t7mp and changed the tomcat-users.xml but that does not seem to work

Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on no new response, I am guess there is no way to have the manager application with t7mp plugin.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [t7mp](http://code.google.com/p/t7mp/), the plugin provides a tomcat for testing purpose.  By using the plugin, you can deploy the web application that you are developing into tomcat and run some tests on it (manual or automated).

If you just want to run manager application, you can as well download tomcat and run it without using the plugin.

Perhaps your use case is different, in which case, please provide more information.

Comment: I wanted the manager application just for convenience. Right now using the t7mp plugin there is no way to just start or stop one application if there are many that are deployed. I have an app that has an admin module and a user module, If I want to just redeploy user module, I will have to shut down the server and start again, which for dev purpose is no big deal, but like i said, i was looking just for convenience.